# Symfony2: If value equals something then change it to something else

Tags: php, database, symfony, switch-statement

I'm fetching and displaying data from a database, but data that means "NO" is represented by a "(", while data that means "YES" is represented by an "X". When I'm displaying the data in the twig, how do I convert the "(" to a "NO" and the "X" to a "YES"?

Here's my twig.html file:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="starter-template">
    <h1><strong>{{ shrub.commonname }}</strong></h1>
        <p>THE FOLLOWING IS DETAILED information about the species <strong>{{ shrub.botanicalname }}</strong> (common name <strong>{{ shrub.commonname }})</strong>.</p>

        {% if shrub == "(" %}
            value=="YES"

        <table class="table table-striped">
                    <hr>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>ph Preference</th>
                <td>{{ shrub.phpreference }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Borderline Hardy</th>
                <td>{{ shrub.borderlinehardy }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Tolerates Wet Soil</th>
                <td>{{ shrub.wetsoil }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Tolerates Moist Soil</th>
                <td>{{ shrub.moistsoil }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Prefers Peaty Soil</th>
                <td>{{ shrub.peatysoil }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Prefers Well-drained Soil</th>
                <td>{{ shrub.welldrainedsoil }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Tolerates Drought</th>
                <td>{{ shrub.drought }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Tolerates Clay Soil</th>
                <td>{{ shrub.claysoil }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Prefers Sandy Soil</th>
                <td>{{ shrub.sandysoil }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Prefers Loam Soil</th>
                <td>{{ shrub.loamsoil }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Tolerates Infertile Soil</th>
                <td>{{ shrub.infertilesoil }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Prefers Rich Soil</th>
                <td>{{ shrub.richsoil }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Tolerates Compacted Soil</th>
                <td>{{ shrub.compactedsoil }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Tolerates City Conditions</th>
                <td>{{ shrub.cityconditions }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Tolerates Pollution</th>
                <td>{{ shrub.pollution }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Tolerates Salt Conditions</th>
                <td>{{ shrub.salt }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Tolerates Windy Conditions</th>
                <td>{{ shrub.windy }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Prefers Shade</th>
                <td>{{ shrub.shade }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Prefers Part Shade</th>
                <td>{{ shrub.partshade }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Prefers Full Sun</th>
                <td>{{ shrub.fullsun }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

        {% endif %}

    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="{{ path('shrubs_index') }}">Back to the list</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="{{ path('shrubs_edit', { 'id': shrub.number }) }}">Edit</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            {{ form_start(delete_form) }}
                <input type="submit" value="Delete">
            {{ form_end(delete_form) }}
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
        </div>
{% endblock %}
```

And my controller if that matters:

public function showAction(Shrubs $shrub)
{
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($shrub);

```
return $this->render('shrubs/show.html.twig', array(
    'shrub' => $shrub,
    'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
));
```

}

Comment: Typically you would write a twig filter for this sort of thing: http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html

Comment: Is this a working piece of code? I see something wrong here - once you use shrub as a string `if shrub == "("` and once you use shrub as an object `shrub.phpreference`. What's the content of `srub`?

Comment: The twig extension option actually worked. Thanks Cerad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a twig extension, like someone suggested above:

```
public function getFilters()
{
    return array(
        new \Twig_SimpleFilter('x', array($this, 'booleanFilter')),
    );
}

public function booleanFilter()
{
    $x = "yes";

    return $x;
}
```

Then the variable: {{ shrub.wetsoil | x}}

Comment: public function booleanFilter($value)
    {
        if ($value == "("){
            $boolean = "no";
    }   else {
        $boolean = "yes";
        }
        return $boolean;
    }

Answer (score 0):

To set a twig variable based on some logic, you need to use something like this.

```
{% set value = '' %}
{% if '(' == shrub %}
    {% set value = 'YES' %}
{% elseif 'X' == shrub %}
    {% set value = 'NO' %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: That just makes the whole table disappear. Thanks for trying anyway